# How to add fields to the default KendoGrid Popup Menu?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, popup, kendo-grid, kendo-window

Is there any way to add fields to KendoGrid's default popup editor?
I know you can make one from a template or make your own KendoWindow, but you lose significant functionality when moving away from the default `editable: "popup"` menu.  The data in my DataSource schema has 20+ fields, but obviously we don't want to show more than ~6 on the actual grid.  Since the popup window refers to the grid's `columns: []`, it seems impossible to add any fields.  The internet/Telerik have yielded no answers as of yet.
My hypotheses for how this might work are:

- Adding columns to grid that don't actually appear in the grid, only the popup
- Manually appending `<input>` fields to the menu
- Making the grid refer to something else besides the columns for what fields to use

Alternatively, I could continue using a custom window, but I am stuck on getting the Grid to properly update in tandem with the popup window's edited or added data.

EDIT: My code

My grid's columns:

```
columns: [
  {
    field: 'Name',
    title: 'Name',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'MCN',
    title: 'P/N',
    filterable: true,
  },
  // {
  //   field: 'ID',
  //   title: 'ID',
  //   filterable: true,
  // },
  {
    field: 'Type',
    title: 'Type',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'Subtype',
    title: 'Subtype',
    filterable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'Value',
    title: 'Value',
    filterable: false,
  },
  {
    field: 'Tolerance',
    title: 'Tolerance',
    filterable: true, //Number/letter combination causes problem?
  },
```

HTML (through Pug)

```
script#popupTemplate(type="text/x-kendo-template")
    p#fields
```

Editable settings:

```
editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        template: kendo.template($("#popupTemplate").html()),
        window: {
              position: {
                    left: "25%",
                    top: "5%"
              },
              width: "50%",
        }
  }
```

Adding the fields to the template:

```
edit: function(e){

        for(let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
              $("<div class='k-edit-label'><label>" + fields[i].name + "</label></div><div class='k-edit-field'><input id='" + fields[i].local + "' class='k-textbox'></div>").appendTo("#fields");
        }  
}
```

The fields array is, of course, an array of the fields to be added.  All the local names are equivalent to the column field names.  However, there are more fields than columns, but this does not seem to matter in relation to the proposed problem.

Comment: Templates are designed for this use case. What functionality are you losing? You could handle the onEdit event and mess with the DOM, but templates and MVVM are meant for these non-simplistic scenarios.

Comment: When using the templates with custom fields, the grid columns no longer update as I type, and the save button doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "custom". You build your template off your grid's model/viewmodel. Include all fields you want posted back to the Create/Update. It should bind automatically. Start with a minimal example, check for console errors, etc.

Comment: I've done a little bit of testing.  Confirmed that it all works in the default popup editor.  Yet, it still doesn't seem that the fields I've made in the template bind automatically.  I figure this because when using the template, required fields in the database error because they are empty.  I am going to update my OP with the code I'm using, perhaps I am doing something improperly.

Comment: Right. Those templates are not dynamic, they are built with the grid so you need to either bind with MVVM or handle the `onEdit` event and `set` a model value or manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I had to add `data-bind='value: [fieldName]'` to the HTML tag.  For some reason, the loop I was using wasn't working with this and I had to revert to manual entries.

For example:

```
.k-edit-label
      label P/N
.k-edit-field
      input.k-textbox#MCN(data-bind='value: MCN')
```